# Uncountable measure space with discrete sigma algebra

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Take $X=[0,1]$, equipped with the discrete metric. Then the topology of $X$ is
$\mathcal{T}=2^{[0,1]}$ and the induced Borel $\sigma$-algebra is again $\mathcal{B}=2^{[0,1]}$. What nontrivial probability measures can one define on the measurable space $(X,\mathcal{B})$?

Comment: All probability measures on this space are discrete (have support on a countable set).

Comment: Is there a simple proof?

Comment: @madprob I don't think that is true. Why can't you do cocountable 0-1 measure or something?

Comment: @mathworker21 There exist sets in $2^{[0,1]}$ that are neither countable nor cocountable. What probability do you assign to those ones? You'll quickly realize these are muddy waters.

Comment: Do you have access to Billingsley's "Probability and Measure" book? You can find the proof there. It's a little more than a page long.

Comment: Can you give a Thm/Lemma #?

Comment: Of course, if you want to post it as an answer (maybe just a sketch) I'll gladly accept it :)

Comment: You can find it in a subsection called "Two impossibility theorems" in the Section 3 (Existence and extension) on Patrick Billingsley's book "Probability and Measure", anniversary edition. It uses some heavy-duty math.

Comment: It is consistent with the usual axioms of set theory that no other such measure exists. It is probably also consistent that such a measure exists, its consistency follows from the consistency of the usual axioms of set theory+ the existence of a so-called "measurable cardinal".

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker do you disagree with madprob that probability measures with discrete support are admissible in this setting?

Comment: @Aryeh I disagree with madprob that it is provable under the usual axioms of set theory that there are only discrete measures. This is really a question of (fairly deep) set theory, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_cardinal

Comment: So I looked in Billingsley's book; he does prove that under choice + continuum, there is no measure $\mu$ on $(X,2^X)$ such that $\mu(\{x\})=0$ for all $x$. I guess @madprob concluded his claim from there, but I don't quite see how it follows.

Comment: Let $M=\{x \in X: P(\{x\}) > 0\}$. If $P(M)=1$, then $P$ has a countable support. If $P(M) \neq 1$, then $P^{*}(A) = P^{*}(A|M^{c})$ is a probability measure such that $P(\{x\})=0$ for every $x \in X$.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker do you agree that continuum + choice are sufficient to establish madprob's claim?

Comment: @Aryeh Yes. I consider the axiom of choice as part of the usual axioms of set theory. The continuum hypothesis is not.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Marczewski and Sikorski, http://eudml.org/doc/209895 , show that in any metric probability space, the support of the measure is contained in a separable sub-space. Doesn't that imply the above result without assuming continuum+choice?

Comment: @Aryeh They don't show what you claim. They show that this holds under the assumption that there is no discrete subspace on which an atomless measure exists; the case where "the answer to Banach's problem is negative".

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Thank you. So what are the most general conditions under which this property holds for a metric probability space? The property being: "the support of the measure is contained in a separable sub-space".

Comment: @Aryeh The result by Marczewski and Sikorski is a characterization, so this is really a pure set theory question.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker is this property implied, say, by continuum+choice?

Comment: @Aryeh Yes, it is.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker many thanks for your patience -- feel free to turn any of the above into an answer I can accept. How about a reference for continuum+choice implying the property I need?

Comment: Also, a reference where the property fails without continuum+choice would be great too!

Comment: For those interested, I seem to have found the answers: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/307126/non-separable-metric-probability-space and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/136134/do-measurable-cardinals-exist-assuming-zfc